# Get a WPF TabControl's current selected Tab's ListView in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, tabcontrol

I got a TabControl based on a basic C#-list in `Request.Params`. Based on that C#-list multiple tabs with a ListView each get generated. Those ListViews are based on C#-Lists named `Values` that are part of `Request.Params`. Now I want to have sorting for those ListViews, hence the Click events.

To implement the sorting I want to call `ListView.Items.SortDescriptions...` but I can't do that, as I don't know how to get the ListView, that's part of the current selected tab, in the code behind.

`ParamsTabs.SelectedItem` and `ParamsTabs.SelectedContent` only hold the actual data, not the ListView element.

```
<TabControl Name="ParamsTabs" ItemsSource="{Binding Request.Params}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Semantic}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListView Name="ValuesList" ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" Background="LightGray">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn.Header>
                                <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="Value" Click="SortValuesList">Value</GridViewColumnHeader>
                            </GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="400">
                            <GridViewColumn.Header>
                                <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="Description" Click="SortValuesList">Description</GridViewColumnHeader>
                            </GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why don't you sort the `Values` source collection?

Comment: There are a few other ListViews in this project that are sorted this way; I didn't feel like breaking the convention to sort the ViewDescriptions.

Comment: Sort in the XAML markup then?

Comment: [Here](https://thomaslevesque.com/2009/03/27/wpf-automatically-sort-a-gridview-when-a-column-header-is-clicked/) is an excellent article from Thomas Levesque. Have a look and you will have sorting for your `GridView`.